# Sybase IN and OUT parameters

Tags: stored-procedures, jdbc, sqlanywhere, out-parameters, jconnect

I'm going nuts about how the Sybase JDBC driver handles stored procedures with mixed `IN` and `OUT` parameters. Check out this simple stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p (IN i1 INT, OUT o1 INT, IN i2 INT, OUT o2 INT)
BEGIN
    set o1 = i1;
    set o2 = i2;
END
```

And here's how I'd call it with JDBC:

```
CallableStatement c = connection.prepareCall("{ call dba.p(?, ?, ?, ?) }");
c.setInt(1, 1);
c.setInt(3, 2);
c.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
c.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
c.execute();
System.out.println(c.getObject(2));
System.out.println(c.getObject(4));
```

But this results in

```
1
null
```

What's going on?? Is that a really wicked bug in the JDBC driver or am I completely missing something? By trial and error, I found this to be a way how it works:

```
c.setInt(1, 1);
c.setInt(2, 2);
c.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);
c.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
c.execute();
System.out.println(c.getObject(3));
System.out.println(c.getObject(4));
```

Now the result is

```
1
2
```

Does the JDBC driver secretly re-order `IN` and `OUT` parameters??

I'm using SQL Anywhere 12 and jconn3.jar

Answer (score 8):

Looks like a bug in the driver.

I suspect the buggy driver expects parameters to be passed/registered in the order (i.e. 1,2,3,4). When you do registerOut(2), the statement apparently forgets you did set(3) :-)

Or, may be, all OUT should be done after all IN. Then again, this is a bug in the driver.

**UPDATE**

Wait, you didn't change the procedure for the second variant? That result doesn't make **any** sense. Unless, as you said, driver does reordering. Which is *unusual*, to say the least.

**UPDATE 2**

I have decompiled the driver. It does some pretty funny games around out parameters, and with all this joggling I feel they have a fair potential for a bug there, but so far I do not see it plainly.

The only funny thing I noticed is that apparently if the parameter at position n is not out, the driver will scan parameters forward until it will find the value; if value is not found, it goes to the next row:

```
  s.registerOutParameter(5,Types.INT);
  ...
  // no out value at position 4, it will go to 5 and get the value
  rs.getInteger(4);
```

**UPDATE 3**

It may be interesting to see the output of all 4 parameters in example 1, i.e.:

```
CallableStatement c = connection.prepareCall("{ call dba.p(?, ?, ?, ?) }");
c.setInt(1, 1);
c.setInt(3, 2);
c.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
c.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
c.execute();
System.out.println(c.getObject(1));
System.out.println(c.getObject(2));
System.out.println(c.getObject(3));
System.out.println(c.getObject(4));
```

Comment: Yes. It's the same procedure, just the call is different. I also suspect that this driver does parameter reordering. But since I couldn't imagine such a horrible flaw in a major RDBMS's driver, I thought maybe I got something wrong...

Comment: I wanted to decompile the driver, but could not find it with google, only new versions. Do you have a link pointing to this buggy driver?

Comment: You can find it here: http://www.sybase.com/detail?id=1041013. jconn3.jar is contained in the jconnect 6 bundle

Comment: I guess you were not fast enough for the bounty... sorry. I don't know about this bounty business. I raised the issue on meta, too, now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84785/preventing-automatic-bounty/90625#90625

Comment: care not about the bounty :-D the issue at hand is what is exciting!

Comment: OMG, you're nuts! OK, I'll have another look into it. Or I'll just file a bug report to Sybase... ;-)

Answer (score 4):

I tried this with Oracle 9.2 and it works as expected.. I think this problem is related to your JDBC driver, not to JDBC itself.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connection connection = getConnection();

    CallableStatement c = connection.prepareCall("{ call p(?, ?, ?, ?) }");
    c.setInt(1, 1);
    c.setInt(3, 2);
    c.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
    c.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
    c.execute();
    System.out.println(c.getObject(2));
    System.out.println(c.getObject(4));

}
```

Output:

```
Connected to database
1
2
```

Comment: The second variation you mentioned in your question results in null, null with my Oracle 9.2 JDBC driver.

Comment: You wrote in the question: "Is that a really wicked bug in the JDBC driver or am I completely missing something?" This is why I tried it with Oracle to ensure this is only in your JDBC driver. Based on this I could write: yes Lukas, this is possibly a bug in your sybase jdbc driver, as works well with Oracle. Anyways: thank you for voting down the only one who spent any time on investigating this issue.. :-(

Comment: Ah, look. You got half the bounty, automatically... ;-)

Comment: thanks :-) it is funny how these valueless reputation points can motivate bored people

Answer (score 1):

```
Below sybase stored procedure works for me
public String IDGEN(String tableName,  Connection con , LOG _log)
    { 
        String strReturnValue = "-1"; 
        try
        {
             CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call usp_NEWPK_string_v6(?,?)}");
             cs.registerOutParameter(2,java.sql.Types.NUMERIC);
             cs.setString(1,tableName);
             cs.setInt(2,0);
             cs.execute();
             strReturnValue = cs.getLong(2) + "";

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            _log.logInstance(" ERROR: [IDGEN] " + ex.getMessage()); 
        }
        return strReturnValue;
    } 
// abobjects.com

create proc usp_NEWPK_string_v6 (@tablename  varchar(32) , @ID  numeric output
          )
as
declare @newValue     numeric
declare @oldValue  numeric
select @oldValue=IDGEN_ID from DB_IDGEN where IDGEN_TableName = @tablename
select @newValue=@oldValue + 1 from DB
 _IDGEN where IDGEN_TableName = @tablename
update DB_IDGEN set IDGEN_ID = @newValue where IDGEN_TableName = @tablename
select @ID  = @oldValue
return
```